# OracleException with respect to Connection issues or Database down

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracleexception

Say I have following `query`

```
private void updateusers()
{
    List<int> listRecords=new List<int>();
    string strQuery="select * from table where role='Admin' and logged_in<=sysdate-1";
    OracleCommand com=new OracleCommand(strQuery,objConnection);
    OracleDataReader reader=com.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
         while(reader.read())
         {
              listRecords.Add(int.Parse(reader["Row_ID"].toString()));
         }
         int i=0;
         foreach(int row in listRecords)
         {
              try
              {
                    OracleCommand command=new OracleCommand();
                    command.Connection=objConnection;
                    command.CommandText="Update table set Status='Y' where Row_ID="+listRecords[i];
                    command.CommandType=System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
              catch(OracleException ex)
              {
                    //log the exception
              }
         }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, Lets assume select query fetches **2000** records and `foreach` will continue to update each `record` and assume at 500th `record` either **DB connection is lost** or say **Database is down** for some reason. Now in these scenarios I want to iterate or try updating same record for 3 times and if it fails 3rd time, come out of `foreach-loop` and stop executing `update` commands for remaining **1500 records**.

> *So is there any particular way to identify these type of Oracle Exceptions or better say Environmental exceptions? Does
>   `OracleException` provide any particular `messageCode` for these type
>   of exceptions?*

Comment: You didn't ask, but even assuming this is a trivial example (it seems a single query would accomplish the update in your example), cases like these seem more suited towards bulk inserts/updates.  It doesn't address your issue, but it may actually resolve the deeper issue by executing all updates in a single transaction, or at the most a few transactions (say one transaction per 5,000 or so updates)

Comment: @Hambone.. You question is valid but I am having log for each records and this I cannot do with single `update` so I have to update individually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ErrorCode` property of `OracleException` class to identify particular type of error.

Comment: Yea but I wanted to know what is the `ErrorCode` for those scenarios.

Comment: You need to reproduce the error you want to detect and inspect ex.ErrorCode for it's value